# service call inside a Ngxs state file

Tags: angular, ngxs

I want to make a service call inside my `auth.state.ts` .
Here is my state file :

```
import { EmitterAction, Receiver } from '@ngxs-labs/emitter';
import { Selector, State, StateContext } from '@ngxs/store';
import { TokenResponse, User } from '../models';
import { UserDetailsService } from '../profile/user-profile/user-details.service';

// actions
export class GetUser {
  constructor(private userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {}
  static readonly type = '[Auth] GetUser';
}
interface AuthStateModel {
  user?: User;
  tokenResponse?: TokenResponse;
}

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: 'auth'
})
export class AuthState {
  constructor(private userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {}

  @Selector()
  static user(state: AuthStateModel) {
    return state.user;
  }

 @Action(GetUser)
     getUser(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: GetUser, userDetailsService: UserDetailsService) {
        console.log('get user');
        // console.log(userDetailsService.userDetailsUrl);

    return userDetailsService
      .getUserInfo()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log(res.message);
          ctx.patchState({ user: res.message });
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
}
}
```

But here it will not get my `userDetailsService` and its methods and properties.
 ***Note*

This `auth.state.ts` file is imported in my `app.module.ts` and also `userDetailsService.ts` too included in `provide` section of `app.module.ts`.

Please help me with this,thanks in advance

Comment: Remove userDetailsService parameter from getUser method and from GetUser action declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by @Zdenek - you need to remove that from the `getUser` signature, as it's already injected into your state, so you can access it via `this.userServiceDetails`.

Additionally, when you do call it the preferred pattern is to use `pipe` and `tap` to process the result rather than subscribing directly in the `getUser` function. 
Using `pipe`/`tap` to formulate the observable, then return it to NGXS so that the framework takes care of subscribing,

Comment: hi @Garth, let's say I want to add `this.userServiceDetails` under `@Selector()` inside `static` `user` method. it will throw an error. So if we remove the `static` and it works. unfortunately, In app `component` file, it will have another error where `@Select(AuthState.user)`  ~> `user` does not exist on type 'typeof AuthState'. do you have any idea?

Comment: no worries. It can be fix by declaring `static user;` before `constructor`